# Create folder if it does not exist in the Google Drive in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, google-api-dotnet-client

I am creating an app in Asp.net MVC in which I want to upload a file on google drive. The following code successfully creating a new folder and saving the file in that folder:

```
public void Upload(string fileName, byte[] bytes)
        {
            if (_userCredential != null)
            {
                var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = _userCredential,
                    ApplicationName = "Test App"
                });

                var file = new File { Title = "Test folder", MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder" };
                var result = service.Files.Insert(file).Execute();
                var saveresult = result.Id;

                Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
                body.Title = fileName;
                body.Description = "A test document";
                body.MimeType = "application/zip";
                body.Parents = new List<ParentReference>() { new ParentReference() { Id = saveresult } };
                var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes);
                FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain");
                request.Upload();
                if (request.ResponseBody == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("User remove access to aplication.");
                }
            }
        }
```

Now the problem is after saving a file once when I am trying to save the file again it creates another folder and save the file in that folder but I want to check that if folder exists than it save the file in that folder and if the folder doesn't exist than it first creates a folder than save that file in that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for more [details.](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list)

```
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data;

// ...

public class MyClass {

// ...

/// <summary>
/// Print files belonging to a folder.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="service">Drive API service instance.</param>
/// <param name="folderId">ID of the folder to print files from</param>
public static void PrintFilesInFolder(DriveService service,
  String folderId) {
ChildrenResource.ListRequest request = service.Children.List(folderId);

do {
  try {
    ChildList children = request.Execute();

    foreach (ChildReference child in children.Items) {
      Console.WriteLine("File Id: " + child.Id);
    }
    request.PageToken = children.NextPageToken;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
    request.PageToken = null;
  }
  } while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(request.PageToken));
  }

  // ...

  }
```